# Perforce: Integrate into earlier revision of target branch

Tags: perforce-integrate

usually perforce integration is to merge code from some revision of source branch to LATEST revision of target branch.

Is there a way to merge code to a specific earlier revision of target branch?

Of course, it's still needed to sync to latest revision for submitting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can sync to the revision you want to integrate to, then run an integrate -h (have revision). Should be one of the checkboxes in the integrate dialog. Or just do it from commandline.

Then once you've done the integrate and resolve, you'll likely have a sync to head and another resolve to go through, but that ought to get you were you want to go.

Comment: The "-h" option is just what I wanted. Thanks @GabeWeiss.

Comment: Great! Could you accept my answer so it shows up on search? :D